# Facebook logout C# SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi
I am having trouble trying to logout of facebook using the FB C# SDK.

Here's a sample of my test

```
var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient();
                    oauth.AppId = fbSection.AppId;
                    string bbc = @"http://www.bbc.co.uk";
                    var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>  {{ "next", bbc }} ;
                    this.NavigateUrl = oauth.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters).AbsoluteUri;
```

The problem is that it´s always redirecting to:

```
http://m.facebook.com/
```

I'm trying to redirect to an external site in this case bbc.co.uk, as in first case I tried redirecting to localhost and had the same problem.

I really wouldnt like to implement a javascript solution as I have already implemented my login functionality server side.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

After some time searching I came across this post: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87109

which suggests to call:

```
this.NavigateUrl =  https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[redirect_uri]&access_token=[access_token]
```

Which worked for me.

Comment: actually the m.facebook.com is a bug with facebook, they are ignoring the next parameter.