# Logging out of Facebook C# SDK on WP7

Tags: silverlight, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, logout

I am trying to add a feature for logging out, which is called in the click event of a ApplicationBarMenuItem, following [the instructions on this blog](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Logout.aspx)

This is what my code looks like:

```
    var oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient();

    var logoutParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
          {
              { "next", "http://www.facebook.com" }
          };

    var logoutUrl = oauth.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters);

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(FacebookLoginBrowser);
    FacebookLoginBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(logoutUrl.AbsoluteUri, UriKind.Absolute));
```

What I expected this code would do is log the user out of Facebook when the Navigated event completes and then displays whatever URL is passed in the parameter (in this case facebook.com). However, what I'm seeing is that it always loads "http://m.facebook.com/" regardless of what is passed in and it does not logout of Facebook. I don't care what it loads after (that would be great, but at this point I just want it to do the logout action so the user can quit and login when they launch my app again). The only way I can successfully logout a user is if they understand when the page loads that they need to scroll down, zoom in, and click "logout" manually at the bottom of the page - which just isn't an acceptable user experience.

I also downloaded the sample code from that blog and it does roughly the same.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023908/facebook-logout-c-sdk) and [this post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87109) and the URL used is pretty close to what is returned by oath.GetLogoutUrl(logoutParameters), but I tried constructing the exact URL with the same result:

```
var logoutUrl = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.facebook.com&access_token="+fbClient.AccessToken);
```

This is definitely a ship stopper for my app, so any help or suggestions anyone can provide would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the domain in the redirect URL did not match the one provided as the Site Domain in the app settings on Facebook. Obviously, no one could see that because you don't have access to my app settings, but it is a bit of a clue that my app couldn't be registered with "http://www.facebook.com" (as I believe the domain has to be unique).

The solution is to use my own website in the next parameter, which in my case is thecruxapp.com. Also, session_key and api_key were required, so in the end the code that worked for me was:

```
string logout_format = "http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?api_key={0}&session_key={1}&next={2}";
string access_token = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fbClient.AccessToken);
char[] tokenSeparator = new char[] { '|' };
string session = access_token.Split(tokenSeparator)[1];

FacebookLoginBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format(logout_format, apiKey, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(session), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://thecruxapp.com"))));
```

I am not experiencing the bug that was linked to in another answer and it wasn't related - both logout and the redirect occur just fine as long as the URL passed into the next parameter matches the Site Domain entered in the apps settings on Facebook.

Comment: I didn't enter anything in my fb apps Site Domain. So this solution doesn't work for me. I still can't login or logout in my wp7 app.

Comment: Facebook requires a Site Domain. My situation is probably the same as yours - my app isn't a site and doesn't use a backend for anything. I had to register a domain and set up hosting in order to get this working. If your app is worth building a native app for, it is probably worth hosting an informational landing page to represent it anyway.

Comment: I can confirm this technique works for now. I set up my site url to point to www.facebook.com for now.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's broken on Facebooks side: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17217

Comment: I marked this as the answer, because it looks like the statement is correct - it must be a bug on Facebook's side. However, the linked bug is likely related but not the behavior I am seeing. Everyone who posted there describes being logged out but not being forwarded correcting to the url they specified in the next param. I am not getting logged out period

Comment: Sorry, removed the mark as answer until I am certain the bug is Facebook's and not in my code

Comment: Prabir linked to the same bug report that you did, so I guess it must be related. I wish I understood more about this. If someone can explain to me how the bug that is linked is causing logout not to happen altogether for my app so the user is required to manually finish logging out, I would really appreciate it. Currently my only workaround is to show text above the browser instructing the user to finish logging out themselves (which is pretty ghetto)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue, no web app as a backend for my WP7 app. 
i found this solution useful http://claudiufarcas.blogspot.com/2011/06/wp7-webbrowser-caching-and-facebook.html but made some changes to the code as there have been some changes to facebook's rendered HTML since the post.

this was working for me http://blog.jocelynenglund.com/?p=21