# facebook logout API - Why Next?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, logout

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 app and have gotten Facebook login working using the C# sdk, but logging out has proven interesting.  I've read this post:

[Cannot Logout of Facebook with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394223/cannot-logout-of-facebook-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk)

which seems to mirror the FB docs which indicate I should navigate to

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=[redirect_uri]&access_token=[token]

However, that doesn't work and silently redirects me back to the facebook home page.

My best guess at the moment is facebook doesn't like the "next" URI I'm providing.  I updated my FB app settings but either they haven't propagated yet, or something else is still not working.

I've seen posts recommending using InternetSetOption, but that API is not available on the phone.

In my application flow, logout leads to navigating to a different silverlight page in my app, so I really don't need the browser redirect for my purpose anyway, so I could just "forget" the access token without actually telling FB to invalidate it, but that seems weak and insecure.

So, while I wait longer to see if the app domain changes propagate across FB's servers and solve the problem I have a different question:

Why should the Facebook APIs care whether I provide "next" or not?  Shouldn't I just be able to tell them to invalidate a token and have it happen?

Is there a logic piece I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: What _is_ the `redirect_uri` you're specifying? Is it properly URL-encoded? Is the `https` session correctly set up and certificates validated and so forth? Does the URL work when you type it in by hand on your desktop browser?

Comment: No, it doesn't work manually. I'm using the silverlight embedded web control, so it is handling SSL internally, but otherwise seems fine. The redirect_uri I'm using is http://www.mydomain.com, where mydomain.com is listed in the application's app domains.

Comment: Don't forget to include the http:// in the query string. :(

Comment: @BitBlitz I updated my answer - this is somewhat possible although not as straight forward as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I wrote an open-source [Facebook login/logout control for WP7](https://github.com/offbysome/Facebook-WP7-Login-Button) that allows this (check the example project).  It works by essentially using the web browser control to navigate to the logout page and then submit the logout form by injecting javascript into the web browser control.  The idea came from this [blog post](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/wp7-facebook-logout-issues/).

The closest thing would be to revoke the extended permissions by issuing an HTTP DELETE to /me/permissions as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions).  Simply forgetting the auth token isn't a bad option either as the access tokens are generally only good for an hour or two unless you asked for offline_access.  And if a user is overly concerned, they can remove your application on their settings page on facebook.com.

Comment: Great idea, however it's a current issue with the C# SDK. See : http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/workitem/5926

Comment: Would be easy enough to do with a simple HttpWebRequest call if that doesn't get patched.

Comment: Yes, true  :)  When I get back to work next week after the holiday, I'll be doing just that!

Comment: @DMCS I updated my answer.  I have this logout working on WP7 (although it is a hack).

Comment: thanks for the update :)  However, my workaround is to use the FB.api() call to do the same thing client side.  Works like a charm, it even passed my QA department just a few days ago.