# Facebook login/logout, modern way

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I had found tons of threads and solutions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558603/logging-out-from-facebook-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-in-wp7), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690991/facebook-logout-api-why-next), [here](http://cloudstore.blogspot.fi/2010/09/clearing-cookies-on-windows-phone-7-or.html) or [here](http://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/wp7-facebook-logout-issues/)). But they all either dated 2010-2011-early 2012, or have comment like "that way is not working anymore", or both.

So, what is the modern way for login/logout to facebook for windows phone (preferably without extra dependencies)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's [FacebookSDK.Net](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/) is what you need. It's Up-to-date.

They have a good [tutorial](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/). On GitHub you can [find samples](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample) as well.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook.Client/FacebookSessionClient.cs)
In `FacebookSessionClient` there is a method:

```
        /// Log a user out of Facebook.
        /// </summary>

   public void Logout()
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookSessionCacheProvider.Current.DeleteSessionData();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CurrentSession = null;
        }
    }
```

Without access token - you can't log in to Facebook. I think you can use it as a Logout action.

Comment: Is it avaivable via nuget? Tutorial is looking good, but there's no info about logout.

Comment: Yep, NuGet command: "Install-Package Facebook". Looks like logout is not supported, so, you can just drop all received tokens.

Comment: //Yep, NuGet command: "Install-Package Facebook". - ok, thanks: google shows several facebook nuget packages. But is loggingout working for you?

Comment: No, we don't use logout in our app, but dropping tokens should work for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i'll try. I don't want to have additional dependency, but i want even less to spend a day on facebook login/logout.

Comment: Updated my answer, there is a log-out method. It just drops tokens, as I suggested before.

Comment: Either i had downloaded wrong package (though, i used "Install-Package Facebook", as it is said http://facebooksdk.net/), or manual is outdated. It is said to use FacebookSessionClient, but only FacebookClient class is avaivable. Also, it is said to use LoginAsync() method, but it is not existed in FacebookClient

Comment: Also, FacebookCsharpSdk (mentioned in FacebookSessionClient) is quite differs from MicrosoftsFacebookSdk. As far as i got.