# ASP.NET MVC: Facebook C# SDK 5.4.1 Logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I know this seems like yet-another post on the subject but the other posts did not help me.

I'm trying to logout my facebook user from my webiste through c# SDK (version 5.4.1) but I can't find a single clue on how to do this. I only find how to do this with previous versions, or javascript logout (which I don't want). 
I've also seen this post [Cannot Logout of Facebook with Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394223/cannot-logout-of-facebook-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk) but I don't know how to get the access token through C# SDK and I even don't know if this method is indeed working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=....&next=...`

Make sure your next url is not any random url but the url which is part of the site url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I also wrote on my question "but I don't know how to get the access token through C# SDK".

Comment: Even if I take the accessToken from Javascript SDK (which isn't really what I wanted) and I try this: string logoutUrl = String.Format( " https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token={0}&next={1}", accessToken, Url.Action("Index", "Support" ) );
return Redirect( logoutUrl ); It's not working! I also entered http://localhost:46678/Support instead of Url.Action but nothing changed! "The given path's format is not supported."