# logout from facebook in windows form c#

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Ive been doing research to logout from my facebook account in my windows form c# app but to no avail. According to this blog by Prabir'blog [here](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Logout.aspx), the GetLogoutUrl is no longer working. for [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023908/facebook-logout-c-sharp-sdk) and [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394223/cannot-logout-of-facebook-with-facebook-c-sharp-sdk) I found here, its not working for me as my newsfeed is displayed in my web browser control. what i want to achieve is my facebook account will be logged out with a single button click.. Anybody can help me please? my codes are below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("https://facebook.com/logout.php?access_token={0}", myToken.Default.token)));

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Updated codes:

```
//logout of the app
    private void logoutBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                string AccessToken = myToken.Default.token;
                GetLogoutURL(AccessToken);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public static string GetLogoutURL(string AccessToken)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();

        var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = AccessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });
        return logoutUrl.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just use this method :

```
public static string GetLogoutURL(string AccessToken)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient();
    var logoutUrl = fb.GetLogoutUrl(new { access_token = AccessToken, next = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" });
    return logoutUrl.ToString();
}
```

you only have to give it a valid AccessToken .

Comment: it works for me ! , could you explain more what happens when you use this method to logout ?